# Write to dynamic collection in MongoDB, with the Apache Beam SDK in Python

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a query with the coll parameter in apache_beam.io.WriteToMongoDB

```
Pcoll
| "Write to Mongo" >> apache_beam.io.WriteToMongoDB(
            uri='someUri',
            db='someDb',
            coll='someColl',
            batch_size=10
        )
```

I would like to like to set the collection name dynamically based on the record, instead of hard coding it.
For ex. if the record is dict. and if it has something like record.tag = 'example', I would like to retreive that and set as coll.

I got some similar references for BigQuery and tried coll = lambda record: record.tag, which doesn't work. It threw an error saying  it needs a string.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [WriteToMongoDB](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.mongodbio.html#apache_beam.io.mongodbio.WriteToMongoDB) does not allow dynamic destinations, as it only takes a string in.

I would suggest opening a Feature Request at [apache/beam](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues).

Are the collection names dynamic, or there is a small subset of them? As a workaround, you could create a combination of a few [filters](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/filter/) + WriteToMongoDBs to allow sending to different sinks.